# Ubuntu Suspend Problem

Tags: suspend

For some reason Ubuntu won't start after Suspend.  I can hear something running in the computer, but nothing shows up on the screen and nothing is happening. I need to turn it off and start it again and everything is fine, until I suspend it again. [This](https://imgur.com/FiNWByv) is a screen shot that I took of the report. How I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Me the same I'm on 14.04 on a 64 bit Samsung laptop. It's like the graphics card or monitor hasn't woke up.

Answer (score 0):

What i've done as a work round is amended the power management settings.

Select 'do nothing ' for lid closed
And 'power down ' for when battery critical.

This is a work round not a solution

Hopefully someone who knows more may throw light on this.

Cos power options need to be done per user, diff or similar could do it better.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another site

Read
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290

Someone's work round was to press ctrl alt f2 to get a terminal then ctrl alt f7 back to gui

This didn't work and ain't tried the forum code